# GFCI trips on separate circuit when another circuit is on

Tags: electrical

[image]When both circuits are on the GFCI on circuit 1 trips but the outlets on circuit 2 stay powered. [image][image: circuit 1] it looks like the blacks are bridged but I’m not sure how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Need more photos of the GFCI connections to help determine if it is installed correctly.  All I can see here is a bunch of wires.

Comment: Looks like a MWBC circuit.  They don't play nice with GFCI's unless done right.  The red is on one breaker and the black is on other breaker(or side of a dual breaker) but share neutral.

Comment: Are you using the LOAD terminals of the GFCI receptacle?  Why?

Comment: Added some more pictures of both outlets. I just bought this home and am finding all these things as I remodel the kitchen.

Comment: Is this a new issue, i.e., did it ever work correctly? If so, suspect a faulty GFCI.

Comment: Yes it used to work fine and still will work fine for a time but then will randomly trip with no load on either circuit.

Comment: The GFCI with the blue plastic wall box is a Leviton model N7899, which is current and has (good) "back wiring" rather than (bad) "back stabbing". The other one seems to be an older model Leviton GFCI, and it's unclear from the photo if that has "back stabbing". Back stabbing is known to produce intermittent failures after years of use because of its design. I would replace that outlet with a current model if indeed it is "back stabbed".

Comment: Have you checked all the wire nutted connections to verify they are secure and not loose?

Comment: It was back stabbed and I replaced it with a new outlet and everything is all good again. Thanks for the help everyone. Cheers!